# How does Genuino Arduino 101 Intel Curie Autocalibration (Ax Ay Az) process works?

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, offset, sensors, calibration

I am reading the source code file [CurieIMU.cpp#L409](https://github.com/01org/corelibs-arduino101/blob/master/libraries/CurieIMU/src/CurieIMU.cpp#L409), made by Intel for Arduino/Genuino 101. I have some questions:

- How does *auto-calibration* work in this specific case? 
  This is not very clear to me.
- Why the *offset* can be assumed to be *linear*?
- Is there any *reference* stating that it is *safe to assume a linear offset for 1 axis calibration*?

The [CurieIMUgetAccelerometerOffset](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CurieIMUgetAccelerometerOffset) reference says that the sensitivity is 3,9 mg.

Given a sensitivity of `+-2g`, I have to use this formula

```
3,9*19,6/32767
```

in order to convert the value in `m/s^2`.

Here is the library code, made by Intel, that computes the correct offset:

```cpp
{
    int bmiOffset = offset / 3.9;

    if (bmiOffset < -128) {
        bmiOffset = -128;
    } else if (bmiOffset > 127) {
        bmiOffset = 127;
    }

    if (axis == X_AXIS) {
        setXAccelOffset(bmiOffset);
    } else if (axis == Y_AXIS) {
        setYAccelOffset(bmiOffset);
    } else if (axis == Z_AXIS) {
        setZAccelOffset(bmiOffset);
    }

    setAccelOffsetEnabled(true);
}
```